# Check which table has the wanted value in a column from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Got 2-4 tables and all of them has "Product_Code" column.

I want to check which one of these tables has the "Product_Code" I'm looking for.

Code mostly only at one table. But in spesific cases it can be on two tables at the same time. Which I don't care which one it gives me. I just need *a table* that has the code.

I can do this with multiple SELECT queries but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do is.

Searched a bit but couldn't get more than join statesments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tangential, but the fact you have to do this indicates a rather severe deficiency in your database design; you should be conforming to the concept of third normal form to avoid issues like this one entirely, while also dramatically improving efficiency and scalability of your database.

Comment: I am aware of deficiency it has. Sadly this is not my db, we simply use a single table that has a column that gives us "which device they are belong to". But this is an old one they they made devices' own tables that requires me to check which one has the code I have then connect my ingedient to that device.

Sadly it runs for years and changing it isn't possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MSSQL, couldn't find the tag sorry checking again

Comment: You can use a view that does a union on the tables and includes the name of the source table. Then select from the view

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that there is some table having a column `device` and there is a related device table? So you'd have to query like `select ... from mytable t left join device1 where t.device = 'DEVICE1' and device1.id = t.device_id left join device2 where t.device = 'DEVICE2' and device2.id = t.device_id ...`? Or have I misunderstood this? a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion to create a view is probably the best solution.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No sadly, table's name is the device name so I can't use WHERE clause. I don't really need the table name, as I use different name in my code. The return can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 doesn't matter. I simply need to know which table has the value since devices connected own spesific table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So using a view would require me add table names as column names and fill that column with "Product_Code" values of their own, did I understand right?

I feel like multiple SELECT statesments would be more efficient than this. I was just wondering if I could do something like ``` IF EXISTS(select1query || select2query) ``` then give which one was "true".

Comment: Hm, okay. So there are those device tables, but there is no column `device` in your other table. Hence you must guess the table. Yes? And you would expect a product in only one of the device tables and only with one row. But in some occasions (maybe faulty data) you find the product in more than one device table. In that case it is necessary to pick one of the two rows arbitrarily, just to make sure you get a one-row match. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, to clarify more: Every device has 5-8 silos. Devices are basically a weigher. Every weigher has spesific ingredients they can weigh but some frequently used ones might be in more than one weigher. Trying to figure which weigher's silos has that ingredient and in the recipe I am saying get that ingredient from that weigher. I am not "aware" of silos, all I know is weigher has ingredients. If it has the ingredient on one of it's silos it knows and pulls that ingredient. I guess the thing Im looking for not possible, since these tables are deficient its understandable..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```
Select 'Table1TableName' as TableName, ProductCode from Table1 where ProductCode = @ProductCode
Union
Select 'Table2TableName' as TableName, ProductCode from Table2 where ProductCode = @ProductCode
Union
Select 'Table3TableName' as TableName, ProductCode from Table3 where ProductCode = @ProductCode
Union
Select 'Table4TableName' as TableName, ProductCode from Table4 where ProductCode = @ProductCode
```

This will give one row for every hit + tablename of where the hit came from.

You can also use dynamic query, but I don't think it will be more efficient than this.

Answer (score 1):

> Every device has 5-8 silos. Devices are basically a weigher. Every weigher has specific ingredients they can weigh but some frequently used ones might be in more than one weigher. Trying to figure which weigher's silos has that ingredient and in the recipe I am saying get that ingredient from that weigher. I am not "aware" of silos, all I know is weigher has ingredients. If it has the ingredient on one of it's silos it knows and pulls that ingredient.

Let's pretend there was an appropriate data model :-) This is basically what the query would look like then:

```
select *
from recipe r
join recipe_ingredients ri on ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
join weigher_ingredient wi on wi.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id;
```

But that could give you ingredients multifold that are present in more than one weigher. We must pick one weigher per ingredient. One way to do this is a lateral join, called `CROSS APPLY` in SQL Server.

```
select *
from recipe r
join recipe_ingredients ri on ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
join lateral
(
  select top (1) *
  from weigher_ingredient
  where weigher_ingredient.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
) wi;
```

In your database there is not one `weigher_ingredient` table however, but one ingredient table per weigher. Let's call these `weigher1_ingredient`, `weigher2_ingredient`, and `weigher3_ingredient`. The query then becomes:

```
select *
from recipe r
join recipe_ingredients ri on ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
join lateral
(
  select top (1) *
  from
  (
    select * from from weigher1_ingredient
    union all
    select * from from weigher2_ingredient
    union all
    select * from from weigher3_ingredient
  ) weigher_ingredient
  where weigher_ingredient.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
) wi;
```

And as has been mentioned in the request comments, you can simply create `weigher_ingredient` as a view. Thus you wouldn't have to union all the tables in every query (i.e. you would use my second query instead of this third one).

It depends on SQL Server's optimizer, how good the execution plan becomes. Ideally, it will see that we are looking for one ingredient_id at a time, and hopefully there are indexes on this ID, so this row will quickly get fetched. The optimizer may further spot that it can stop searching once it finds the ingredients in one of the tables, because of `TOP (1)`. If it doesn't yet, we can still hope for a future version that can :-)

Comment: I am currently using as @Ruben Ravnå's answer. On C# environment, with foreach loop It queries using ExecuteScalar() (which stops query at first result). I am aware it isnt always "less code is faster" but from joining tables and creating view etc it feels like it will be slower (yeah well we are talking about milliseconds here but...). I asked to question to learn if there is a better syntax or something that could be more efficient. Looks like there isn't BUT nonetheless, I learned a lot. So thanks a lot for contributing.

Comment: What is often most costly when selecting data is the dialog between your app and the DBMS. If you have a loop to tell the DBMS "give me the data for the first ingredient", "give me the data for the second ingredient", etc. that will probably be much slower than a mere "give me the data for all ingedients in the recipe". As a rule of thumb: The less queries you send to the DBMS the better.

Comment: Creating a view is a one-time thing. And from then on, you write queries like my second query and the DBMS will expand this internally to my third query and find the best execution plan for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write dynamic sql query. For example

```
exec 'select * from '+@tableName+' where Product_Code='+@productCode+''
```

and you can use it in loop.